# Import inline SVG inside Sketch

Tags: svg, sketch-app, import

Is it possible to import an inline SVG directly into Sketch?
I want to convert my inline SVG into a file without importing an external library or copy and paste the code inside an editor to save it as an SVG file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no native way to do this in Sketch.
So plugins to the rescue!

[image: SVG Insert in action.]

The [SVG-Insert](https://github.com/tankxu/svg-insert) Sketch plugin is exactly what you need to get the job done.

Comment: No problem @ThomasBck 

Comment: Thank you so much @spjpgrd and Thomas for asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

As of Sketch 55, you can just copy / paste SVG code into Sketch, no plugin needed.

Reference: https://www.sketch.com/updates/

> Create new layers from SVG code: Paste SVG code straight into Sketch to create new layers anywhere on your Canvas.